# How to combine two list containing dictionary with similar keys?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Assuming that there are two python list with the same structure like this:

```
var1 = [{'a':1,'b':2},{'c':2,'d':5,'h':4},{'c':2,'d':5,'e':4}]
var2 = [{'a':3,'b':2},{'c':1,'d':5,'h':4},{'c':5,'d':5,'e':4}]
```

In my case, i need to combine both of those list, so i'll get this value :

```
result = [{'a':4,'b':4},{'c':3,'d':10,'h':8},{'c':7,'d':10,'e':8}]
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)-based one-liner comprehension:

```
result = [{k: d1[k]+d2[k] for k in d1} for d1, d2 in zip(var1, var2)]
```

This assumes that two `dicts` at the same index always have identical key sets.

Comment: I was trying to get this using the values too and it messed up my head. the usage of `d1[k]` is much more straightforward.

Comment: Beat me to it, although I'd use `d1[k] + d2.get(k, 0)` in case the second dictionary is missing a key.

Comment: @zwer I see your point. Yet the OP claims the lists have the same structure. Also, the choice of `var1` as the key "base" is rather random, so I'll leave it.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yeah, I was contemplating that. But one would have to parallelly iterate two dicts' items with no guarantee of order which makes it inconvenient.

Comment: How does `for k in d1}` work here? Is it because the dictionaries have the keys in common it does, but will throw an exception once there's a key in d1 that doesn't exist in d2?

Comment: I think this is the most simple and the flexible way to be implemented in other case too, thank you very much for helping me @schwobaseggl..

Comment: @TheStupidEngineer Yup. It will throw a `KeyError` in that case.

Comment: @TheStupidEngineer @ schwobasegg, if only it has different keys, this is my solution so far for the unsimilar key `[Counter(d1) + Counter(d2) for d1, d2 in zip(var1, var2)]`

Answer (score 2):

Use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to put the code in one line,

```
result = [{key : d1.get(key, 0)+d2.get(key, 0) 
            for key in set(d1.keys()) | set(d2.keys())}     # union two sets
            for d1, d2 in zip(var1, var2)]

print(result)
[{'a': 4, 'b': 4}, {'h': 8, 'c': 3, 'd': 10}, {'c': 7, 'e': 8, 'd': 10}]
```

This code takes into consideration the case that two dictionaries may not have the same keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
var1 = [{'a':1,'b':2},{'c':2,'d':5,'h':4},{'c':2,'d':5,'e':4}]
var2 = [{'a':3,'b':2},{'c':1,'d':5,'h':4},{'c':5,'d':5,'e':4}]

res = []
for i in range(len(var1)):
    dic = {}
    dic1, dic2 = var1[i], var2[i]
    for key, val in dic1.items():  // dic1.iteritems() in python 2.
        dic[key] = dic1[key] + dic2[key]
    res.append(dic)

>>>print(res)
[{'a': 4, 'b': 4}, {'c': 3, 'd': 10, 'h': 8}, {'c': 7, 'd': 10, 'e': 8}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var1 = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 2, 'd': 5, 'h': 4}, {'c': 2, 'd': 5, 'e': 4}]
var2 = [{'a': 3, 'b': 2}, {'c': 1, 'd': 5, 'h': 4}, {'c': 5, 'd': 5, 'e': 4}]

ret = []

for i, ele in enumerate(var1):
    d = {}
    for k, v in ele.items():
        value = v
        value += var2[i][k]
        d[k] = value
    ret.append(d)

print(ret)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, another zip-based one-liner that will work even if the dicts are uneven in the both lists:

```
result = [{k: d1.get(k, 0) + d2.get(k, 0) for k in set(d1) | set(d2)} for d1, d2 in zip(var1, var2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help?

```
ar1 = [{'a':1,'b':2},{'c':2,'d':5,'h':4},{'c':2,'d':5,'e':4}]
var2 = [{'a':3,'b':2},{'c':1,'d':5,'h':4},{'c':5,'d':5,'e':4}]

combined_var = zip(var1, var2)

new_d = {}
list_new_ds = []

for i, j in combined_var:
    new_d = {}
    for key in i and j:
        new_d[key] = i[key] + j[key]
    list_new_ds.append(new_d)

list_new_ds = [{'a': 4, 'b': 4}, {'h': 8, 'c': 3, 'd': 10}, {'c': 7, 'e': 8, 'd': 10}]
```

To explain, the zip function merges the lists as a list of tuples. I then unpack the tuples and iterate through the keys in each dictionary and add the values for the same keys together using a new dictionary to store them. I then append the value to a list, and then re-initialise the temporary dictionary to empty before looking at the next tuple in the zipped list.

The order is different due to dictionary behaviour I believe.

I am a novice, so would appreciate any critiques of my answer!